# In ASP.NET MVC, How to return an xml document to a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like some guidance in returning an XML doc from a controller to a view.
In my view, I'd like to traverse the XML doc using JQuery. There are plenty of online examples using JQuery for this use.

I have a PortfolioList() Controller below, which right now just returns the view, but I would like to figure out how to RETURN THE XML RESPONSE. You'll noticed below that I'm writing the XML response to a local file just for testing purposes...

Do I need to cleanly create a model for this ?

```
    public ActionResult PortfolioList()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument xmlRequest = new XmlDocument();

        bool rzInitialized = nitializeRz();
        if (rzInitialized == false)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Rz Init has failed. Check if Rz is running";
            return View();
        }
        bool rzConnected = ConnectToRz();    

        ViewBag.Message = "Here you may view a list of portfolios and exposures.";

        // Build Portfolio Select request here !
        RequestBuilder rzRequest = new RequestBuilder();

        // REQUEST FOR PORTFOLIOS !
        string portfoliosRequest = rzRequest.PortfoliosRequest("Portfolios");
        string **portfoliosResponse** = RzClient.sendRequest(portfoliosRequest, false);

        // DEBUG REQUESTS !!
        if (Debugflag)
        {
            rzRequest.DebugOutput("portfolios", portfoliosRequest, portfoliosResponse);
        }
        DisconnectFromRz();

        return View("PortfolioList");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you should be creating models for all your views that contain any dynamic data. It's always cleaner that way.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it as follows.

```
public ActionResult PortfolioList()
{
    //Your code
    ....
    return this.Content(yourXml, "text/xml");
}
```

Comment: If you do this, what does the view look like?

Comment: Design time view is empty but runtime response will be yourXml

Comment: That won't work for OP's usecase - "In my view, I'd like to traverse the XML doc using JQuery."

Comment: In that case, this could be a different `Action` which is being called by his `original view using jQuery`. What he is looking for is `RETURN THE XML RESPONSE.` Should be able to manipulate as required.

Comment: My view doesn't have much yet except for a <script> tag to load JQuery libraries and ViewBag.Title message. And yes, runtime response will be my XML Response.

Comment: Hi Kaf, your idea actually get me somewhere. Meaning, I can actually return the XML string back to PortfolioList controller, and IE cleanly display the XML result. Wow that's a great start ! Now I'm trying to figure out how to intercept it in the cshtml view .

Comment: Like for example in some tutorials it's all database driven, so in the view I see code like this "@model MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre", then you use Razor syntax @foreach (var album in Model.Albums){ ... }, so that would be my next approach...

Answer (score 1):

If returning xml document from controller action is all you about a better idea is creating a custom action result.

```
public class XmlDocumentResult: ContentResult
{
    public XmlDocument XmlDocument { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (XmlDocument == null)
        return;

        Content = XmlDocument.InnerXml;
        ContentType = "text/xml";
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

Now you can return xml from an action as,

```
public XmlDocumentResult GetXml()
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    ...

    return new XmlDocumentResult { XmlDocument = xmlDoc };
}
```

Comment: Mark, That looks very interesting indeed. I've seen this idea posted in a similar xml-related post, but they were discussing the MVCContrib on Codeplex (XmlResult action). In any case the post also contained an override to the ExecuteResult() method. Thank you, as I will experiment with this pronto !!! :-) - Bob

Comment: InnerXml will not have the entire document.  This is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Based on another developer's advice, I'm going the Json data format route. It turns out that **returning an XML doc** from an asp.net Controller back to a View is a COMPLETE nightmare (i.e. I can return the XML doc itself to the browser, but I cannot figure out how to use jQuery to process the xml nodes).

I've gone the route of deserializing the XML doc on the server side, and returning a JsonResult to my View (i.e. using JQuery's Ajax routine to call into my controller).

sample XML serialization code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx#Y0

Answer (score 0):

I found a jQuery code sample online which works for me !
The code sample parses an xml document as follows (the url is http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Xml/xml_test1.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml,
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Some problem.");
        }
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    //find every Tutorial and print the author
    $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function () {
        $("#output").append($(this).find("Title").text() + "<br/>");
        $(this).find("Category").each(function () {
            $("#output").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
        });
        $("#output").append("<br/>");


    });
}
```

However, I do not understand something like this does NOT work (but rather just dumps the entire innerText of every single element onto my page)...sorry about the commented lines:

```
//$.ajax({
//    url: "/Portfolios/getPortfolios",
//    type: "POST",
//    dataType: "XML",
//    async: true,
//    success: function (data) {
//        if (!data)
//            alert("No xml data returned.");
//        else {
//            var $xml = $(data);
//            $xml.find("portfolioSummary").each(function () {
//                $('.XmlResp').text("DUDE!");         // text($(this).text());
//            });
//            //alert($xml.text());

//            $('.XmlResp').text("Wow are we getting somewhere ?!!!");
//            $('.XmlResp').replaceWith($xml.text());

//        }
//    },
//    error: function (error) {
//        alert("failed");
//    }
//});
```